# Shortest example of a class with two "synchronized" variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to implement the simplest possible example of a class that represents a (geometric) circle and can print its own data.

`Circle` is a class with two variables, `self.radius` and `self.area`. The only requirement is that, when changing one variable, the other changes too.

What's the absolute simplest way to do this? Is it with the `property` decorator?

Here's my attempt.

```
import math


class Circle:

    def __init__(self, radius=1):
        self._radius = radius
        self._area = math.pi * radius**2

    @property
    def radius(self):
        return self._radius

    @radius.setter
    def radius(self, radius):
        self._radius = radius
        self._area = math.pi * radius**2

    @property
    def area(self):
        return self._area

    @area.setter
    def area(self, area):
        self._area = area
        self._radius = math.sqrt(area / math.pi)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'radius {:.2f}  area {:.2f}'.format(self._radius, self._area)


c = Circle()
print(c)

c.radius = 110
print(c)

c.area = 3
print(c)
```

I'm curious if there's a way to accomplish the same thing in **less lines of code**, or if this is the best that can be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simpler way would be only using a single attribute inside the class, and providing the second by calculating it from the first upon request.

```
import math

class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius=1):
        self.radius = radius

    @property
    def area(self):
        return math.pi * self.radius**2

    @area.setter
    def area(self, area):
        self.radius = math.sqrt(area / math.pi)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'radius {:.2f}  area {:.2f}'.format(self.radius, self.area)


c = Circle()
print(c)

c.radius = 110
print(c)

c.area = 3
print(c)
```

Furthermore, if **less lines of code** is the goal, we can shorten the `area` property code bit, see the following modified code:

```
import math

class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius=1):
        self.radius = radius

    area = property(fget=lambda s: math.pi * s.radius ** 2,
                    fset=lambda s, area: s.radius = math.sqrt(area / math.pi))

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'radius {:.2f}  area {:.2f}'.format(self.radius, self.area)


c = Circle()
print(c)

c.radius = 110
print(c)

c.area = 3
print(c)
```